# DataGridView Cell Click( The data has a null value. Cannot caDataGridView CellClickll method or property on null values.)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview, sql-update

I connected the textboxes to the datagridview on cell click, in order to modify from the textboxes, a column (8) is empty, even if in the SQL Server table I set it to allow null value, in the visual studio when I click it gives me an error( The data has a null value. Cannot caDataGridView CellClickll method or property on null values.), here is my code

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Try
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            connection.Close()
        End If
        connection.Open()
        i = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridView1.SelectedCells.Item(0).Value.ToString())
        cmd = connection.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.CommandText = "Select * From StoricoLotto WHERE ID=" & i & ""
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(table)
        Dim dr As SqlClient.SqlDataReader
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        While dr.Read
            txtId.Text = dr.GetValue(0).ToString()
            dtpDataEstrazione.Text = dr.GetDateTime(1).ToString()
            txtRuota.Text = dr.GetString(2).ToString()
            txtEstratto1.Text = dr.GetValue(3).ToString()
            txtEstratto2.Text = dr.GetValue(4).ToString()
            txtEstratto3.Text = dr.GetValue(5).ToString()
            txtEstratto4.Text = dr.GetValue(6).ToString()
            txtEstratto5.Text = dr.GetValue(7).ToString()
            txtRicercaEstrazioni.Text = dr.GetString(8).ToString()
        End While
        connection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message) 'show error msg'
    End Try
End Sub
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        txtId.Text = row.Cells("id").Value.ToString
        dtpDataEstrazione.Text = row.Cells("Data_Estraz").Value.ToString
        txtRuota.Text = row.Cells("Ruota").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto1.Text = row.Cells("Estratto1").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto2.Text = row.Cells("Estratto2").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto3.Text = row.Cells("Estratto2").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto4.Text = row.Cells("Estratto3").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto5.Text = row.Cells("Estratto4").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto1.Text = row.Cells("Estratto5").Value.ToString
        txtRicercaEstrazioni.Text = row.Cells("RicercaEstrazioni").Value.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I wanted to suggest something, but - sorry - it may sound rude but this looks like a collage of all possible mistakes one can find in a small piece of code, from the first line to the last. -- Not just about the syntax. -- You can find a lot of example related to master-detail data binding in this platform.

Comment: @Jimi
Thank you for your comment, but I would have been more grateful if you had told me where the errors are, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `Try/catch` block spanning all the code in a method (not talking about what the `Catch` block does) / Connections have to be opened and closed in-place, declared with a `Using` statement, same the DbCommand / `Convert.ToInt32(....Value.ToString())` / `SELECT *` / string concatenation + useless final  `& ""` / Un-disposed DataAdapter used to fill a DataTable that nobody uses (not disposed either) / `while [DataReader].Read()` loop to set the text of TextBox Controls (you can of course set it just once) / more... This is just about the code itself, not the functionality of this procedure.

Comment: I'm 100% on board with what Jimi has said in his 1st comment, you've got layers of issues there.  Along with what has already been mentioned, I think your entire process is quite wrong and I admit I'm making a couple assumptions here.  I guessing in your UI you've got a grid which is used by the user to select a record, then you're using textboxes to display it for editing?  If that's the case this whole block of code could be replaced by simple data binding a DataTable properly and avoid the extra hits your making to the DB on cell click

Comment: As for you actual issue, in this context, the fact that you've set the DB to allow nulls is at best meaningless, at worst exasperating the problem.  The issue is likely dr.GetString(8) = DBNull.Value which can not be converted to a string.  So your choice is to make sure you don't have DBNull.Value in there when loading the data, or check that it's not equal to DBNull.Value before trying to treat as a string

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have to admit that as a neophyte, I can make mistakes, so I would be grateful if I could have a sample code from you, thanks.

Comment: I solved it so, okay I can do it better?
Thanks in advance for future advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.RowIndex >= 0 Then
        Dim row As DataGridViewRow
        row = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        txtId.Text = row.Cells("id").Value.ToString
        dtpDataEstrazione.Text = row.Cells("Data_Estraz").Value.ToString
        txtRuota.Text = row.Cells("Ruota").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto1.Text = row.Cells("Estratto1").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto2.Text = row.Cells("Estratto2").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto3.Text = row.Cells("Estratto2").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto4.Text = row.Cells("Estratto3").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto5.Text = row.Cells("Estratto4").Value.ToString
        txtEstratto1.Text = row.Cells("Estratto5").Value.ToString
        txtRicercaEstrazioni.Text = row.Cells("RicercaEstrazioni").Value.ToString
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You should remove this code entirely and bind your TextBox Controls to the same DataSource you have set to the DataGridView. After that, everything is automatic, except in case these TextBoxes could also be used to change the data, since this requires validation. If the data should not be changed, use Labels instead of TextBoxes (or make the TextBoxes read-only).

Comment: To bind a TextBox to a data source, just add a Binding: e.g., `txtRuota.DataBindings.Add("Text", [the DGV DataSource], "Ruota", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)`, assuming the corresponding Column in the data source is named `Routa`. -- You can add these bindings in the Constructor of the parent Form.

Comment: @Jimi SOLVED[Yes]
Yes, actually, I use the textboxes for editing and this code works perfectly and quickly. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Glad to see your problem solved, you can click '✔' to mark the answer as the accepted answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.